# Grid Mograph Effector

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want a grid that samples values of 3D noise based on the dimensions. Sample values can clamp into color ranges. Repeating the process within that voxel, over and over again, creating recursive cubes. Appropriately sized Cubes can cloned to their respective group. Render Instances for performance and Mograph Effectors for additional manipulation. Not sure if this can be done like C4D since TP were used also. Just want to see if I can get something similar to the images attached. Thank you for your time.[image]